# Configuring multiple host header names when doing TFS deoployment

Tags: tfs

We are using TFS Build & Release to deploy a web application to different environments.

For one of the environments, we need to configure more than one host headers however the current task used for managing the IIS App seems to allow only a single host header.

I wonder if there is a way to somehow configure the existing standard task to handle more than one host header or there is some other TFS extension that could support this:
[See screenshot of deployment environment configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/im3I0.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can add another Manage IIS App task, and add a new host name. Other information should be the same as the first Manage IIS App task:

[image]